# Free java data visualization library?

Tags: java, visualization

I'm looking for a free Java library to visualize some data. I want to do something similar as the following two images. Is there any possibility? I first thought of prefuse, but this isn't developed since 2007. So any oher libraries?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, Prefuse has been moved to [github](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse). You may want to take another look.

Comment: But if I look at the homepage, the latest release is from 2007 nevertheless.

Comment: I added another bounty to find an answer for the second part of my question. I'm still looking for a timeline library.

Answer (score 26):

Have you considered looking at [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/)?

Graphviz (short for Graph Visualization Software) is a package of open-source tools initiated by AT&T Labs Research for drawing graphs specified in DOT language scripts. It also provides libraries for software applications to use the tools. Graphviz is free software licensed under the Eclipse Public License.

You can do some fairly cool stuff with it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I awarded this answer the bounty. But I will spend another one for the second part of the question. I'm stilling looking for a timeline library.

Answer (score 9):

Try [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/), which seems to be the successor of Prefuse and may be a good alternative option. It is written in JavaScript, but a [Java Graphical Toolkit](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/protovis-java/) is available.

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is the successor of Protovis today. (Recommended by Protovis.)

Comment: I alsready considered Protovis, but this sentence is a little bit scary: "Please note that this is a research prototype! It is not intended to be a production-ready toolkit and we do not provide software support as of this time. The code is also missing many of the library routines familiar to Protovis-Javascript users."

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is my concern too.

Comment: The latest Protovis 3.3 release was in September 17, 2010. 
Latest update states: June 28, 2011 - Protovis is no longer under active development. We recommend switching to D3.js!

Comment: @CostisAivalis but how would we use D3 in java?

Comment: @chhh: There is a GWT wrapper library around the d3.js library. https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3

Comment: @CostisAivalis oh, I meant a java.swing solution

Comment: JavaScript is meant to run in a browser and Swing in a desktop. Since browsers run in desktops, if you add a browser to your desktop application you can run JS. https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser could be what you need.

Answer (score 9):

For the timeline part, you should really consider [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes.html) which contains annoted timelines, ...

Comment: I can't find an example how to do something like I need to do

Comment: @Roflcoptr here is an example of what i was referring to: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Comment: I awarded a bounty to this answer since it is the closest that I can use. But it it still not really the thing I'm looking for. I don't want to visualize values against a time line but rather events or something like this. So I don't need a chart.

Comment: @Roflcoptr Try modifying the code and check in the documentation. Certainly there is a way to modify what appears on the chart and how it appears.

Answer (score 5):

[GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/) is a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Check ou:

- http://processing.org/
- http://www.axiis.org/ (not java)
- http://gephi.org/

Further links can be found at:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_visualization
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_visualization

Answer (score 4):

An other alternative is to use [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net) framework. If you are looking for browser/Javascript based libraries as well, checkout [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Answer (score 4):

Another library you could consider is JGraph. It works mainly with graphs but you can easily implement a timeline as a one. The project can be found on GitHub https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx and was recently updated.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to no doubt do a lot of customization, but Google's Chart Tools offers a lot of flexibility and options (http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).  I have not done anything as involved as the images that you pasted above, but it was fairly easy to set up various charts using the Google Visualization API.

It might be worth it to post your images on the Google Visualization API group (http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api?pli=1) to see if anyone has done more involved charts like those you've proposed above using the Visualization API...

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised this hasn't been listed. I used **jFreeChart** a while back: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: how do you generate time lines or graphs with that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are explicitly looking for a swing library, ignore this answer!
But in the world of web, [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) are my favorites. Back-end could be implemented in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind to use javascript solution [timeglider](http://timeglider.com/widget/index.php?p=intro) is what you need for the second screenshot.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I ment if you are developing a web application or if you dont mind to use a javascript solution. I have updated my answer too but seems like you dont prefer:)